# Using Two different JAX-WS client implementations

Tags: java, web-services, cxf, java-metro-framework

I have two internal client libraries. One uses [JAX-WS RI](https://jax-ws.java.net/) (I think its Metro now) and the other [Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/). Both of these clients need to be loaded in the same Web App. The reason both cannot use Metro is because one of the clients needs [XmlBeans](http://xmlbeans.apache.org/) (despite my best attempts at XJB transforming the schema I could not get JAXB to work).

The obvious solution I guess is to port the other client to CXF however what if I create a custom fake [`Provider`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b27/javax/xml/ws/spi/Provider.java#Provider) that uses `ThreadLocal` variable that says which real provider to use then have a static method to set the `ThreadLocal` variable before using the client.

Is that a bad idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating ThreadLocal based provider which works quite nicely.

You can see the code at this [gist](https://gist.github.com/agentgt/98566cdafd446ee37d8f#file-threadlocalprovider-java).

You can switch from JAXWS and CXF like:

To force a provider

```
   ThreadLocalProvider.setProvider(ThreadLocalProvider.JAXWS_RI_PROVIDER);
```

OR

```
   ThreadLocalProvider.setProvider(ThreadLocalProvider.CXF_PROVIDER);
```